# Tapping on google assistant list always fires fallback intent for the first time

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

My Dialogflow agent is using an 'Actions on Google Rich Message' List response object to display options on the Google Assistant platform.

The list options work perfectly when testing on the Dialogflow console. However, when testing through the Google Assistant Simulator or Google Assistant app on a mobile device, the list option does not work on the first try. It works only when selecting an option the second time. Below is my intent code which generates the list.

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
    conv.ask('Hi welcome to micro strategy. I am Emily, your virtual assistant. Please tell me how can I help you');
    conv.ask(new List({
        title: 'Please choose',
        items: {
            ['SELECTION_KEY_GET_CALENDAR_EVENTS']: {
                synonyms: [
                    'Get calendar events',
                ],
                title: 'Get calendar events',
                description: 'Lets you retrieve calendar events',
            },
            ['SELECTION_KEY_MODIFY_EVENTS']: {
                synonyms: [
                    'Modify calendar events',
                ],
                title: 'Modify calendar events',
                description: 'Lets you modify calendar events'
            },
        },
    }));
});
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you must have an intent that handles the `actions_intent_OPTION` event, which is what is fired when you touch for the first time an element in the list.

Lists / Carousel always fire that event. If no intents can handle the `actions_intent_OPTION` event, then the conversation goes to the Fallback intent.

Refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#list), section **List > Requirements > Interactions > Voice/Text** : *Must have an intent for touch input that handles the actions_intent_OPTION event*.

Let me know if it helps, Marco

Comment: you are saying "actions_intent_OPTION" and in their document, I can see "actions.intent.OPTION". Which one is correct? "actions.intent.OPTION" didn't work for me.

Comment: When you create the Intent in Dialogflow, the Event must be "actions_intent_OPTION". With the underscores. The documentation linked to don't talk about the setting in Dialogflow and other documentation is vague on this point, but @Marco is correct.

Comment: @BimalKumar https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#helper_intents -> this is the doc to the map between the event names and the intent names. The one you need to put in Dialogflow is the event name.

Comment: I have enabled fulfillment for fallback intent and defined a handler for it. Inside the handler function, there is a check for the option text value. I have defined events in the intents and based on the option values, we can fire the appropriate events, This works fine for me.